# Can't change color of status bar

Tags: android, xamarin, material-design, android-appcompat

I am trying to theme my app to follow the material Android look. My project is a Xamarin.Android project, which targets API 23, but the minimum API target is 16. So I have to use the AppCompat library to have the same design on all APIs.

I have followed these guides: [Material Theme](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material_theme/),[Beautiful Material Design with the Android Support Design Library](https://blog.xamarin.com/add-beautiful-material-design-with-the-android-support-design-library/),[Android Tips: Hello AppCompatActivity, Goodbye ActionBarActivity](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-appcompatactivity-goodbye-actionbaractivity/) and created these files:

- Resources/values/styles.xml:

  ```
  <resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <item name="colorPrimary">#F44336</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#D32F2F</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>
  </resources>
  ```
- Resources/values-v21/styles.xml

  ```
   <resources>
   <!--
      Base application theme for API 21+. This theme replaces
      MyTheme from resources/values/styles.xml on API 21+ devices.
   -->
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
  </style>
  </resources>
  ```
- MainActivity.cs

  ```
  using Android.App;
  using Android.Widget;
  using Android.OS;
  using Android.Support.V7.App;

  namespace TestThemeApp
  {
      [Activity(Label = "TestThemeApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
      public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
      {
          protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
          {
              base.OnCreate(bundle);

              // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
              SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I'm just trying to make the the toolbar red, and the status bar a darker red, but the status bar color won't change. This is what it looks like:

[image: Status bar won't change]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What API level is the device you're testing on? I believe this will only work on API 21+ devices. On older platforms, AppCompat emulates the color theming where possible. At the moment this is limited to coloring the action bar and some widgets. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: I'm running API 24 on the emulator

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that i have found the most elegant solution based on the other answers:

The only thing i changed was added the flag in the `OnCreate(Bundle bundle)` function:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
 {
       if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= (int)BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                Window.AddFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);

       base.OnCreate(bundle);

       // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
       SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
 }
```

And that's it! The style files do the rest, and on older version of android, the status bar just won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your style (Resources/values-v21/styles.xml)

> ```
> <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item> > 
> <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/cobalt_light</item>
> ```

I personaly prefer to handle it in the `onCreate` method of the activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_very_dark));
    window.setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_darker));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple workaround you can change your primary color to the  desired color of your status bar and it will change the color of your status bar automatically.

NOTE: It is a work around till you find the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add a flag at the top of the MainActivity and set the bar color at the end.

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // First check if the current SDK is >= 21. Else it will cause trouble
        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 21)
            Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        SetBarColor();
    }

    public void SetBarColor ()
    {
        if((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 21)
            Window.SetStatusBarColor(Color.ParseColor("#FF0000"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet to change statusbar color:

```
public void setStatusBarColor(Activity context, int color) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                Window window = context.getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,color));
            }
        }
```